# Not always work long click on ExpandableListView child item

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onlongclicklistener

I implement ExpandableListView DragNDrop for child item using this source https://github.com/sreekumarsh/android/tree/master/Drag%20N%20Drop. All main functional are in class, which extends ExpandableListView. It override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) method, and long click functionality I indicate like this:

```
    int flatPosition = pointToPosition(x, y);
    dragRatio = getHeight() / screenHeight;
    long packagedPosition = getExpandableListPosition(flatPosition);

    Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            event.setLocation(x, y);
            touchHandler(event);
            pressedItem = true;
        }
    };

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && getPackedPositionType(packagedPosition) == 1) {
        if (dragOnLongPress) {
            if (pressedItem) {
                mDragMode = true;
                pressedItem = false;
            } else {
                pressedItem = true;
                **handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 500);**
                return true;
            }
        } else if (x < dragOffset) {
            mDragMode = true;
        }
    }
```

But, have some problem. Long click works not always. How I can to do this more reliable (without using GestureDetector class).

Comment: What do you mean by not always work? What is your desired behavior?

Comment: When detected long click, I set flags, and next In dependence of Action, I select or move child item. if You can, open link in my question and find class DragNDropListView. It has all code in touchHandler method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my personal implementation, which seems to work fine.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                vibrator.vibrate(100);


                Log.i("imageclick", "LONG_CLICK");
            }
        };

whateverViewYouWantToDetectLongClick.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Animation a = null;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("imageclick", "ACTION_DOWN");
                    handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 750);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    Log.i("imageclick", "ACTION_UP");
                    handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.i("imageclick", "ACTION_CANCEL");
                    handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }


                return true;
            }
        });
```